# I'm calculating the sum of numbers in a series but I only want the console to output the final sum but I don't know how

Tags: c#

```
int a=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());  

int b=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

int c = a / b;

int b2 = b;

    for(int i=0; i<=c; i++)
{
    b += (b2 * i);
    Console.WriteLine(b-b2);
}
```

this is basic code that asks for a base number, and a secondary number. only numbers divisible by the second number are added together. I only want to output the final number, but right now it outputs every step it takes and I'm to noob to know an easy solution.

Comment: Move the last line to outside the loop.

Comment: Could also be though of as moving the close brace `}` to before the `Console.WriteLine`  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the console.WriteLine() Outside the for loop to avoid printing it in every step.

Comment: huh. I guess I  better go rest. thanks!